# How to pass props to child components in react-router tree

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, parent

I have a route model made up in react-router. I want to know how to pass props between my components in this setup - is it possible?

```
   <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
      <Route path='/posts' component={Posts} />
      <Route path='/albums' component={Albums} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About} />
   </Route>
```

Say for example, I initialise my state in the Layout component (the idea being that all it's children can access the state); how would I pass the state value to them, and also trigger functions in the parent component passed down via props?

Is this possible, as it would be if the component were directly nested in it's parent, or am I thinking about this in the wrong way with regards to routing? If so, is there an alternative solution?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You may want to look into using [redux](http://redux.js.org/) for this.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. Haven't started with redux yet but now's probably the time to get my hands dirty :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You can use [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) in `Layout` component. Here's an example in ES6:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
        layoutState: React.PropTypes.object
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {layoutState: this.state};
    }

}
```

Then just declare the context in child/grandchild components:

```
export default class Users extends React.Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        layoutState: React.PropTypes.object
    }

    render() {
        const {layoutState} = this.context;
        // then just use your layoutState and return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but having read the official docs, it seems to strongly recommend against this feature a) as the API is likely to be updated, and b) it makes your code harder to understand (no sure exactly why this is, but I'll take their word for it!). Is there a more stable way of accomplishing this? For example, would it just be easier to use Redux for this?

Comment: Well I don't think there's any other way you can initialize the state in Layout and pass the variable to Layout's children. Since the child components were already instantialized before the instantiation of `Layout` so react-router can pass them to `Layout` as `props.children`.